# Apply multiple arguments for each row using R

Tags: r

I need help in getting the sentences from the paragraphs with the given keywords and get rid of unnecessary information.

Below is the example of file that I have.

```
Heading     Years    Text
Head1       2015     <rrrt> I am a boy and I <rrr2> like a girl <t44> from my class. She is pretty. /rr /r    /r I am cute.
Head2       2015     She is cute. She is beautiful.
Head3       2014         Hi, I am Jane. I play guitar. May is my friend.
```

I would like to extract the sentences with the given keyword (am). Sentences that contain "am". Also, for each sentence, I would want to get the heading and years. And to get rid of unnecessary informatino such as <***> ,  /r.

Below is the output that I would like to achieve using R:

```
Heading     Years    Text
Head1       2015     I am a boy and I like a girl from my class.
Head1       2015     I am a cute.
Head3       2014     Hi, I am Jane.
```

Thank you in advance.

Updated:

```
Heading     Text
Apple       "Jane is pretty." Good afternoon
Orange      Tom said she is pretty. Also she is kind hearted. Tom listened in class.
Pear        Added Lim, He is a great guy...and clever. Mary turned her head away.
```

The output I want to get is:

```
Heading     Text
Apple       "Jane is pretty."
Orange      Tom said she is pretty. Also she is kind hearted.
Pear        Added Lim, He is a great guy...and clever.
```

I would want to capture what people said. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could split the 'Text' column  at the end of each sentence in to a `list`, `grep` to extract sentences that have `am`, convert the `list` to `data.frame` using `stack`, and then `merge` with the original dataset.

```
df2 <-  stack(setNames(lapply(strsplit(df1$Text, '(?<=[.])(?=\\s*)\\s+', 
          perl=TRUE), grep, pattern='\\bam\\b', value=TRUE), df1$Heading))[2:1]
colnames(df2) <- colnames(df1)[c(1,3)]
res <- merge(df1[1:2], df2)
res
#  Heading Years                                        Text
#1   Head1  2015 I am a boy and I like a girl from my class.
#2   Head1  2015                                  I am cute.
#3   Head3  2014                              Hi, I am Jane.
```

NOTE: If the 'Text' column is `factor`, use `as.character(df1$Text)` in the `strsplit`.

#### Update

For the new dataset, we can remove the characters between `<` and `>` and also `/r` using `gsub` and then proceed as before.

```
v1 <- gsub('\\<[^>]+\\>\\s*|/r+\\s*', '', df1N$Text, perl=TRUE)
                              Hi, I am Jane. Head3
df2N <- stack(setNames(lapply(strsplit(v1, '(?<=[.])(?=\\s*)\\s+', 
    perl=TRUE), grep, pattern='\\bam\\b', value=TRUE), df1N$Heading))[2:1]
colnames(df2N) <- colnames(df1N)[c(1,3)]
res1 <- merge(df1N[1:2], df2N)
res1
#  Heading Years                                        Text
#1   Head1  2015 I am a boy and I like a girl from my class.
#2   Head1  2015                                  I am cute.
#3   Head3  2014                              Hi, I am Jane.
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Heading = c("Head1", "Head2", "Head3"),
Years = c(2015L, 2015L, 2014L), Text =
c("I am a boy and I like a girl from my class. She is pretty. I am cute.", 
"She is cute. She is beautiful.", 
"Hi, I am Jane. I play guitar. May is my friend.")),
.Names = c("Heading", "Years", "Text"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df1N <- structure(list(Heading = c("Head1", "Head2", "Head3"), 
 Years = c(2015L, 2015L, 2014L),
 Text = c("<rrrt> I am a boy and I <rrr2> like a girl <t44> from my class. She is pretty. /rr /r    /r I am cute.", 
 "She is cute. She is beautiful.", 
 "Hi, I am Jane. I play guitar. May is my friend.")),
 .Names = c("Heading", "Years", "Text"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Will this work if some paragraphs don't contain a sentence with 'am'?

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid  The second row doesn't have `am`.  It still worked.

Comment: @akrun Hi, thanks for helping. Is it possible to add in df1$Years for the line in df2? When I use merge, the data is mixed up.

Comment: @poppp I think I forgot to paste one line that changes the colum names.  Please try it now.

Comment: @akrun it works! thank you so much :)

Comment: @akrun May I know how to remove <all the things in here and brackets>, and \n from Text? Thanks

Comment: @akrun updated, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I would like to seek help from you. I would want to extract sentences that have "", eg: ("Hello, I am me." Good afternoon.) I would want to just extract and have this outpu: "Hello, I am me." @akrun

Comment: @poppp Can you describe a little more.  It's not very clear.  Also, a dput of that string will be good to get the structure correct.

Comment: @poppp Can you post that as a new question.

Comment: I have updated my post. Do take a look, thanks @akrun

Comment: @poppp The updated post doesn't show any patterns.  In the first line, we are extracting between `""`, but that is not the case for 2nd and 3rd.  Also, please consider to post that as a separate question.

Comment: I want to capture what people said. Or could you teach me how to extract words that are inside "extract everything in here". @akrun

Comment: @poppp The first one is easy, but 2nd and 3rd is without any pattern.  Can you post the first row as a new question.

Comment: @akrun I have updated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253107/extract-part-of-sentences-in-r

Answer (score 2):

```
head <- c("Head1", "Head2", "Head3")
years <- c(2015, 2015, 2014)
Text <- c("I am a boy and I like a girl from my class. She is pretty. I am cute.","She is cute. She is beautiful.", "Hi, I am Jane. I play guitar. May is my friend.")
#As strsplit doesn't work on factors, converting text to characters
df$Text <- as.character(df$Text)
df <- data.frame(head, years, Text)


words <- unlist(strsplit(df$Text, "[.]"))
test <- words[grep("am", words)]
i <- 0
a <- array()
for(i in 1:length(test)) {
a[i] <- grep(test[i], df$Text)
}
newdf <- data.frame(df[a, 1:2], test)

newdf
#head years                                       test
#1   Head1  2015 I am a boy and I like a girl from my class
#1.1 Head1  2015                                  I am cute
#3   Head3  2014                              Hi, I am Jane
```

Comment: hi @RonakShah, thank for helping. I have an error when running the for loop. The error is: Error in `[.data.frame`(df, a, 1:2) : object 'a' not found

Comment: ohhk. I need to declare a variable as array. I have updated the code.

Comment: it works, thanks for your help :)